Cannot access rails backend with fetch (500 Internal Server Error)
I'm trying to access an api backend in a React/Rails app. I'm referencing this tutorial (it's a little outdated, but works with a few tweaks). I can't seem to connect to the backend. How can I resolve / troubleshoot these errors?
Fetch console error:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
Rails server log error:
Started GET "/api/v1/playlists/index" for ::1 at 2024-09-05 08:59:11 -0400
Processing by Api::V1::PlaylistsController#index as */*
  Playlist Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists"
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/playlists_controller.rb:5:in `index'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 1], ["record_type", "Playlist"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/playlists_controller.rb:5:in `index'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/playlists_controller.rb:5:in `index'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Allocations: 7845)



fatal (exception reentered):

javascript/components/Playlists.jsx (truncated for clarity)
import { Table, message, Popconfirm } from "antd";
import React from "react";

class Playlists extends React.Component {

  ...

  loadPlaylists = () => {
    const url = "api/v1/playlists/index";
    fetch(url)
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.ok) {
          return data.json();
        }
        console.log(data.json())
        throw new Error("Network error.");
      })

      ...

  };

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Table className="table-striped-rows" dataSource={this.state.playlists} columns={this.columns} pagination={{ pageSize: 5 }} />

      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Playlists;

controllers/api/v1/playlists_controller.rb:
class Api::V1::PlaylistsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /playlists or /playlists.json
  def index
    @playlists = Playlist.all
    render json: @playlists
  end
end

routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'page#index'

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get 'playlists/index'
      post 'playlists/create'
      delete 'playlists/:id', to: 'playlists#destroy'
    end
  end
end

Let me know if I'm missing anything here. Thank you!
***UPDATE: I'm finding that all other models work, when I replace "Playlist.all" in the controller. For example, using the Track model, which has a youtube video ID, and a reference to the playlist(s) it belong to:
controllers/api/v1/playlists_controller.rb:
class Api::V1::PlaylistsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /playlists or /playlists.json
  def index
    @playlists = Track.all
    render json: @playlists
  end
end

Works perfectly fine. Obviously the table above isn't filled out because the fields are different, but the app is able to access Tracks without returning a 500 error..

In case this isn’t obvious, the title error is because a 500 error is encountered and rendered as HTML - the browser cannot parse html as JSON

The logs appear truncated, Please add the complete error to the question

@AD7six - that's all there is, the log literally stops  after fatal (exception reentered):

Well that's not helpful :). I suggest to retitle and edit the question to focus on the main problem here (the cause of the server side 500) and not the frontend side effect of that error. None of the js code is actually relevant to the root cause here and you could IMO delete it. I am not a ruby dev but hopefully then someone can answer why render json: @playlists is generating an error and what to do about it. gl :).

@AD7six thank you - I'm going to try to rephrase this question a little better...

The problem is here and caused by assuming an unsuccessful response contains JSON. Your example clearly contains an HTML error page.
    fetch(url)
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.ok) {
          return data.json();
        }
        console.log(data.json())
        throw new Error("Network error.");
      })

You would be better off logging data.text():
    fetch(url)
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.ok) {
          return data.json();
        }
        console.log(data.text()) // UPDATE THIS
        throw new Error("Network error.");
      })

Also, I wouldn't assume that a failed request is only caused by a network error either.

Good tip - thanks!
